# How to identify the state status in flink?

Tags: apache-flink

Is there a way to monitor the status of state in Flink?
I mean that if I use the state in my Flink application, then I want to know the status or the ongoing value of the state in Flink.

Is there a way to achieve my issue?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear for me what you mean with "status". Can you clarify that? You can store and retrieve state in Flink, but I don't see how that's related to "status".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query your state using [Queryable State](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/queryable_state/)